# how to redirect all pages to the root, without affecting css files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I changed the design of a site to a single-page design. Now I want all the requests for the previous pages to redirect to the homepage (domain.com).

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=302,NC,L]
```

but if I use it, my CSS files won't load!

any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add exceptions as conditions for that rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=302,NC,L]
```

So that it won't redirect images/css/scripts to the homepage.

Comment: thanks. I actually decided to just list all the pages as individual rules instead. Otherwise I lose campaign tracking codes.